# Why does my code only show one post?

Tags: php, html, database, post, forum

I have been developing a social network, and a key function is to be able to post on other users' profiles. However, my current code will only show one post. Also, it seems to be the first post that is shown. I have tested this by creating new accounts, and writing a test post. The code does show this first post, but if I try it again, only the first post is visible. The code is as follows:
The code to send post to database:

```
$person = "profile.php?id={$id}";
$post = $_POST['post'];
if($post != "")
{
    $data_added = date("Y-m-d");
    $added_by = $session_username;
    $user_posted_to = $id;
    $post = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $post);
    $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES ('', 
                                             '$post', 
                                             '$data_added', 
                                             '$added_by', 
                                             '$user_posted_to')";
    $commandQuery = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die ("Couldn't send post");
}
else
{
    echo "You have to fill in the post form...";
}
```

The code to retrieve it (and display it):

```
$getPosts = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                           FROM posts 
                          WHERE user_posted_to='$id' 
                       ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15") or die("Couldn't find any posts");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPosts))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
    $added_by = $row['added_by'];
    $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];
    $querya = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                             FROM members 
                            WHERE username='$added_by' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($querya))
    {
        $user_added = $row['id'];                           
    }
    $user_added = "profile.php?id={$user_added}";
}

echo "
    <div>
    <h3><a href='$user_added'>$added_by</a> - $date_added </h3>
    <p> $body</p>
    </div><br />
    ";
```

If anyone needs some more of the code, like my database connection, just comment.

Comment: Using a `while()` loop to fetch a SINGLE row from a `LIMIT 1` query is a pretty big symptom of cargo cult programming. You really should rewrite your two nested queries into a single `JOIN`ed query. Plus you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks...

Comment: You can avoid the double query with `SELECT p.id, p.body, p.date_added, p.added_by, p.user_posted_to, m.id  FROM posts p JOIN members m ON p.added_by = m.username WHERE p.user_posted_to = '$id' ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 15`. Also you have serious **SQL Injection** problems.

Comment: ....... Good luck with that social network!

Comment: It is a bit bare, but you can check out my website at [link] (http://www.destinationstation.site40.net/index.php). The domain is just an old one I was using to test it, and is not the name of the site (which is yet to be decided)

Answer (score 1):

In your while cicle you fill in some variables but you do not use them.
You use `echo` only outside the cycle, so just once, and thus you print only the values of the last istance of the `while` cycle.

Try

```
    $getPosts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_posted_to='$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15") or die("Couldn't find any posts");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPosts)){
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $body = $row['body'];
                    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                    $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                    $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];

                    $querya = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$added_by' LIMIT 1");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($querya)){
                        $user_added = $row['id'];                           
                        }
                        $user_added = "profile.php?id={$user_added}";
                    echo "
                    <div><h3><a href='$user_added'>$added_by</a> - $date_added </h3><p> $body</p></div><br />";
                                                }
```

Comment: By the way I do agree with the comment saying you need some serious enhancement. mysql functions are deprecated, and you are prone to injection. Prepared statements in a PDO could solve both problems.

Comment: Would make more sense if you had said that he is using `echo` to print the posts outside the loop so it only prints it once.

Comment: @Prix thanks for the comment, I edited the answer to make it clearer